# Is there a way to empty trash and compress a folders on all of my Thunderbird IMAP accounts with a single click?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, trash

OK, actually that will take clicks: one click for emptying the trash, and the second click to compress the folders. I want to do this on all my IMAP accounts in Thunderbird, so I don't have to do it one-by-one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Xpunge (0.5) Plugin

It can run both on demand and on a timer and will clean out multiple mail accounts, compress and clear trash etc

I've used it for a couple of years now it definitely helps keep things tidy